# Mysql nested subquery

Tags: c#, mysql, subquery

I have a page that I'm trying to spice up a bit..

Basically my current SQL select is generated randomly from options chosen on a page.

However, I'd like the default sort order to be random; but from what I've read, I should avoid both nested subqueries in MySql, and order by *rand*.

But, what if I order by *rand* the limited number of records returned (less than 50?) with a nested subquery.

Is this a bad idea?  And would this be a problem with a larger table of say 2kk + rows?

Here's what I'm thinking of doing

```
select * from (
  select a.*,b.* 
  from a 
  left join b on b.id=a.id 
  where a.isactive AND etc etc 
  order by a.id DESC // select say page 2 of 50 newest records
  limit 50,50
) tblrand order by rand() // randomize the order of those 50 records
```

**EDIT*****

changed the inner order by a.displayorder to order by a.id DESC to better reflect the situation since the default sort order (if none specified) is newest records (ie... id sorted desc order)

and added some comments

***** SOLVED *********** (however i'd still like to know how this would pan out.. ie. how bad would it be performancewise for mysql... tnx in advance)

tnx dbsman..  i was thinking of the problem in a different way.
at first i wanted totally random rows, which as i explained would be a pain in the butt... (i got mixed up in what i wanted to do myself :)

but i think i found a solution that works like a charm with my problem doing it in the application side

```
//code that gets **Dataset ds** goes here
var rand = new Random();
var result = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => rand.Next());
lst.DataSource = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Can't you randomize in your application instead?  I don't think order by rand() is too bad, it just puts extra load on your database, probably unnecessarily.

Comment: the content of the sql is generated randomly, that includes teh AND statements and the joins (i may have 1 or more). I also implement the limit clause which makes doing this in the app a pain in the butt. I'd need to do a select COUNT(*) on my first query to get total record count, then choose record numbers that may have gaps in them then run the same query again.... so it seems i'd be making the db do more work by running the query twice.... this seemed like harmless given that i'll be using limit clause to order by rand on a smaller recordset

Comment: when you give order by a number, it uses that as the column to sort by, so this would not give you what you want.

Comment: actaully it does... the initial order by selects say 50 newest records... the outer select randomizes those newest 50 records

Comment: before executing this, just get the count of the total number of rows returned, and according to that set the limit variables and execute the query...

Comment: Completely agree with Michael Buen. Was about to write the same :)